# How to display the user edit-picture form in custom block?

Tags: 7, forms, users, panels

I am trying to customize the user edit page in Drupal7 using Panels for user-edit page. How can i display the user edit-picture form in any specific region in Drupal 7. In my panels, i added a custom text in my sidebar region as:

```
<?php
drupal_get_form("edit-picture") ;
?>
```

However, it does not show anything. I got the form id by looking at the css. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

The ID you pulled from the DOM isn't the form ID, unfortunately. It's just the ID of the user image picker fieldset.

Take a look at the [User Picture Field](http://drupal.org/project/user_picture_field) module. I haven't used it, so I can't personally vouch for it. However, it does make the user picture a field, which adds a lot of flexibility. I think Panels will let you move the field to the place where you want it to appear. You should also be able to use the [editablefields](http://drupal.org/project/editablefields) module to make the image editable in the display.