# Customize the user-edit page

Tags: 7, users, theming

I want to customize the user-edit page. So in my template.php in my custom theme i direct Drupal to look for my custom template as:

```
function mytheme_theme() {
return array(
// The form ID
'user_profile_form' => array(
// Forms always take the form argument.
'arguments' => array('form' => NULL),
'render element' => 'form',
'template' => 'templates/user-profile-edit',
),
);
}
```

This works fine as Drupal is able to pick my custom user-profile-edit.tpl.php. Inside that file i have rendered some elements as :

```
<?php

print render($form['form_id']);
print render($form['form_build_id']);
print render($form['form_token']);

print render($form['field_birthday_user']);
print render($form['field_real_name_user']);
```

And so on.I have two questions...How do i get the user picture field, username, password, and email id fields to edit and how do i get to save the profile, i.e., how to get the save button. For the first part i tried doing:

```
print render($form['account']);
```

However, this does not displays the user picture.

For the second part, i tried doing this :

```
<input type=”submit” name=”op” id=”edit-submit” value=”Save”  />
```

at the end of my custom user-profile-edit.tpl.php. However i get an error regarding syntax.

Would appreciate any suggestions especially regarding the user picture thing.

Thanks

Comment: what i need is something along the lines of this question:http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63504/display-the-user-edit-picture-form-in-custom-block-in-drupal-7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
print render($form['picture']);
```

Yups..thats all that is required...but i am still stuck at that save button...i have used, for the time being,`print drupal_render_children($form);` to get the save button..if someone can suggest how to do this by code then i would implement it

Comment: the standalone submit button would be something like render($form['submit']) . Tip: use Devel module and dpm($form) and the form array becomes easy...

Answer (score 2):

```
 print drupal_render($form['actions']);
```

that should output the save button

Comment: Read How do I write a good answer to a question? http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/7656

Answer (score 0):

```
print drupal_render_children($form);
```

will take care of the hidden and submit inputs. Try to print_r or dpm() your $form to render the other fields.

or if you use profile2 module this could be handy http://thanhsiang.org/faqing/node/178

Comment: hi...thanks for the prompt reply..FYI i am not using profile2...just adding custom fields

Comment: hi...how do i get only the user picture form...i want it to be placed at the beginning so ...

Comment: what i need is something along the lines of this question http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/63504/display-the-user-edit-picture-form-in-custom-block-in-drupal-7