# User Edit Profile Custom

Tags: 7

I am working on Drupal 7.  I am wotking on user-edit -profile page

I created a **user-profile-edit.tpl.php** 
which is working fine

now here i mention

```
    **`<div class="ptag"><?php print render($user_profile['field_first_name']);  ?>
  <?php print render($user_profile); ?></div>`**
```

which is also working

Now  Edit or Update button is not coming .

Can anybody tell me how to get submit buttons etc 
Thanks

Comment: what is written in your user-profile-edit.tpl.php?

Comment: i have edited the question

Comment: Check http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/64468/customize-the-user-edit-page issue, you might get a solution.